# How to select just one item of each table visual

Tags: powerbi

Is there a convenient way for selecting only one item from each table visual with a simple shortcut-click combination?

I have selected a `red` color from **colors dimension** table visual and then with a control key down, I selected `triangles` from **shapes dimension** visual. Now I want to keep `red` color but I want to select `circles` instead of `triangles`.

The only way I find is:

1. Deselect the `triangles` item with a control key down. So I see results for all shapes. This step I would like to avoid.
2. And then clicking `circles`.

If I click `circles` without a control key, then the `red` color becomes unchecked. This way is not desirable in case there are lots of one-choice-dimensions, because they all become unchecked.

Comment: I think you'll need to use slicers instead of clicking on the table to do this.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Hi Alexis, I found a solution:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. It can be set up in PBI options / Report setting by ticking Change default visual interaction from cross highlighting to cross filtering:

[image]